# How to design a table that can reference two different table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am designing a schema for a very simple contact management software. I have two tables, viz. `person` and `customer`. A person is an individual while `customer` is meant as a company or individual or group of people intending to have some business relation.

Now, both entities can have one or more `address`. So, how do I design an `address` table/entity where a `person` can have `1:m` relationship with the `address` and at the same time `customer` can also have `1:m` relation with `address`.

How to approach schema design for this? What are the common anti-patterns when doing this so that I can avoid this?  Answers should address this from a transactional processing perspective, not necessarily from an analytics perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to to create a metadata table called: **EntityAddressLinkTable**. Metadata, in this context, refers to data that provides information about other data.

**EntityAddressLinkTable** stores information about the relationships between entities and their addresses.

This covers your requirement for a: *a person can have 1:m relationship with the address and at the same time customer can also have 1:m relation with address*  and also makes an attempt to  try adhere to the principal of the separation of concerns somewhat.

A basic structure of what you have scoped out is as follows using traditional ER modelling. Noting the basic structure does not deal with the relationships between addresses.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(255),
);

CREATE TABLE Address (
    AddressID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Street NVARCHAR(255),
    City NVARCHAR(100),
    State NVARCHAR(100),
    Zip NVARCHAR(20),
    Country NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

Now for the clever bit :-) to enable you to link and join it all together,
the **EntityAddressLinkTable** table acts as a junction table to manage these many-to-many relationships effectively. Without this table, you would need separate fields in the Address table for person and customer, leading to redundancy and complications and it would become horrific to manage over any kind of developement lifecycle.

```
-- Creating the EntityAddressLinkTable
CREATE TABLE EntityAddressLinkTable (
    EntityAddressID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    EntityID INT,
    EntityType NVARCHAR(50), -- Can be 'Person' or 'Customer'
    AddressID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AddressID) REFERENCES Address(AddressID),
);
```

This approach can allow you to add addresses to other entities within your database quite easily and provide scope to expand the functionality to other parts of your system. I hope this answer helps you with your design.

Comment: Definitely the best answer of the three available right now because it a) supports the additional Customer multiples stated in the question, b)the mentioned future potential of this design, and c)the better db performance for regular transactional queries. 

You could also add NOT NULL constraints. If your db dialect supports FK relationships with multiple fields & you're using db for data validation, you could add the equivalent of @White-Owl `check (person_id is null or customer_id is null)` above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your presentation of **Person** and **Customer** as two completely separate things, you would require two associative tables **PersonAddress** and **CustomerAddress** to facilitate a relation to **Address**. There is no other way to do this, without resorting to anti-relational “tricks” like the ones already mentioned in other answers.

[image]

Nevertheless, your Person/Customer can most probably be modeled into a [Subtype](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) cluster, potentially normalizing other parts of your model too. That way **Address** will reference a **Contact** basetype, instead of the **Person** and **Customer** subtypes.

[image]

Of course you will need to expand the model, make any necessary changes, add subtypes, etc. to match your exact requirements. For example, the model below may match more closely to your requirements regarding customers.

[image]

Comment: Please reserve comments for the [purposes they are intended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and keep them to a minimum.  If you need to have an ongoing discussion about a particular design, please do so in [chat].  Back and forth commentary is needlessly distracting and adds clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Choose what you like:

1. Make two separate address tables. One for person, one for customer.

```
create table person_address (
   person_id null referencing person(id),
);
create table customer_address (
   customer_id null referencing customer(id),
);
```

2. Make two separate fields referencing to separate table.

```
create table address (
   person_id null referencing person(id),
   customer_id null referencing customer(id),
   check (person_id is null or customer_id is null)
);
```

3. Foreign key without system support, only by a client:

```
create table address (
   owner_id null,
   owner_id_type char(1) check(owner_type in ('P', 'C'))
);
```

4. Combine `person` and `customer` table into one with a flag `person_or_customer` and have just one simple `address` with simple FK

```
create table person_or_customer(
   id primary key,
   is_this_person bool,
   common_field1,
   ...
   common_fieldN,
   person_only_field1,
   ...
   person_only_fieldN,
   customer_only_field1,
   ...
   customer_only_fieldN,
);
create table address (
   owner_id null referencing person_or_customer(id),
);
```

Comment: None of these allow for the necessary 1:m relationships while keeping normalization.